# VSCode esLint plugin is giving Parsing error in every TypeScript file

Tags: typescript, eslint, vscode-extensions

I am working in a Nest JS TypeScript project where I have enabled eslint in my VsCode environment.

So after installing I did restarted the vscode.

My project has a `tsconfig.lib.json` file with the following content:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "../../dist/libs/connector-client"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "test", "**/*spec.ts"]
}
```

And my higher level tsconfig.json has this content:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "ESNEXT"
    ],
    "paths": {
    Project specific folders etc.
    }
  }
}
```

However once I have enabled the eslint, it starts giving this error in all typescript file:

Parsing error: Cannot read file 'c:\users\pradipm\clients\myproject\cliet_dir\project_folder\tsconfig.app.json'.eslint

Even if I keep on placing a tsconfig.json in the respective path as reported in the above error, it complaining the tsconfig.json is not available one level up.
And it continues till c:\ drive.

The .eslint.rc is this:

```
module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    project: ['./tsconfig.json'],
    sourceType: 'module',
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'],
  extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  ignorePatterns: ['.eslintrc.js'],
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
  },
};
```

And my vscode `settings.json` is this:

```
{
    "projectManager.vscode.ignoredFolders": [
    
        "node_modules",
        "out",
        "typings",
        "test"
    ],
    "eslint.format.enable": true,
}
```

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show the full error message.

Comment: Apology. I just updated the text of the error and added .eslintrc and settings.json also.
If some clue can be given will be helpful.